# How to send SMS with foreach looping depending on mysql query result?

Tags: c#, mysql, sms, gsm

I have a GSM modem wavecom fastrack m1306b, I also made a sample Windows Form Application for sending the SMS, the thing is I don't know how to proceed on sending SMS with foreach looping, I have a table in my database with phone numbers stored, and a query on my database class to retrieve it.

```cs
db = new DBConnect();
var eventMessage = db.getEventContents();
string message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, eventMessage);
if (this.port.IsOpen)
{
        List<string> numbers = new List<string>(db.getPhoneNumbers());
        foreach (string num in numbers)
        {
            try
            {
                sms.sendMsg(this.port, num, message);
                i++;
                sendingProgress.Value = i * sendingProgress.Maximum / numbers.Count();
                MessageBox.Show("Announcement Sent to :" + num);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                i++;
                sendingProgress.Value = i * sendingProgress.Maximum / numbers.Count();
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to send announcement to :" + num);
                ErrorLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Below are the functions from my DBConnect class:

```
public IEnumerable<string> getPhoneNumbers()
{
    string query = "SELECT contact_no FROM students";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string numbers = (string)reader["contact_no"];
                yield return numbers;
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> getEventContents()
{
    DateTime eventday = new DateTime();
    eventday = DateTime.Now;
    int day = eventday.Day;
    int month = eventday.Month;
    string query = "SELECT event_header,event_content FROM events WHERE DAY(date) = '" + day + "' AND MONTH(date)='" + month + "' LIMIT 1";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string eventAnnouncement = (string)reader["event_header"] + "\n\n" + (string)reader["event_content"] + "\n\n";
            yield return eventAnnouncement;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it wont send, so far I have tested sending sms using sample project from CodeProject and it works without a problem, I checked the ErrorLog.txt file and it says No success message was received,can someone point out to me the error, it would be a great help for me.

Comment: can You please check if this list is fulfilled ? : List<string> numbers

Comment: yah its fullfilled i had placed a messagebox to display the contents for every element inside it and it worked, thats why im having a hard time figuring out where i went wrong in the code, the only downside is it worked on the catch section